# Rails 3 Minitest tests load very slowly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

I'm taking over an old Rails 3.2 application that uses Minitest and Capybara for testing, and the tests are unbearably slow. Running the full test suite with `rake test` takes over 7 minutes to run, and a good portion of that time is spent waiting for something to load (no tests are actually running). To make it worse, for some reason the `rake test` command appears to run 3 separate test suites consecutively, each of which requires the same 30-45-second wait time *after* the basic Rails environment has been loaded.

After trying some application preloaders, I established that the Rails app itself only takes around 15 seconds to load. Another 30-45 seconds (times 3) is spent on loading something in test_helper.rb.

I found advice online to check how long it takes Bundler to load all my gems. But when I ran the benchmarks for that, it didn't appear that my gems are the problem.

Finally, I did some benchmarking in **test_helper.rb** and figured out that the following line is responsible for all of this delay. I know I've seen this command in Rspec, and I've never known it to take more than a second or so to execute.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

My questions:

1. What does the above line do?
2. This doesn't have anything to do with loading the Rails environment and my application, correct? (Note that the above line takes around 30 seconds to execute even when I'm using a preloader like Spring.)
3. Can you give me any advice on how to figure out what is taking so long to load, and ideally reduce the wait time or allow it to be preloaded?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What does the above line do?
> 2. This doesn't have anything to do with loading the Rails environment and my application, correct? (Note that the above line takes around 30 seconds to execute even when I'm using a preloader like Spring.)

It loads the Rails application and environment-specific config.  Without knowing something more about your application / environment and how you're using Spring though, I'm not really able to tell you what might be taking so long.

> 3. Can you give me any advice on how to figure out what is taking so long to load, and ideally reduce the wait time or allow it to be preloaded?

I wrote up something like this on my blog not too long ago.  A lot of the article is about colorizing Minitest output, but there's also some information on finding slow-running tests.

http://chriskottom.com/blog/2014/06/dress-up-your-minitest-output/